Ubuntu 22.04 VM 'has not reported package information' in Landscape
On a new Ubuntu 22.04 VM, it can be registered with Landscape and shows up in the list of computers. However, when viewing packages in Landscape, the 'computer has not reported package information'.
landscape-client --version

24.08+git6391-0landscape0

Looking up in /var/log/landscape/package-reporter.log are these two lines:
2024-11-10 00:24:34,255 WARNING  [MainThread] Couldn't determine which hash=>id database to use: server UUID not available

2024-11-10 00:24:40,502 INFO     [MainThread] Queuing request for package hash => id translation on 500 hash(es).

What do I need to do to resolve this? I can do a 'sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade' with no issues and outwardly ping.
Thanks in advance!
~Jim
